# Is it possible in AWS to subscribe to EC2 created/started/stopped/terminated events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a utility in Lambda which does automatic DNS registration via an intelligent automated process. Instances that are created with a `Name` tag including `XXXXXX` and a `autodns` tag set to `true` will have Route 53 records created and deleted when these instances are created and deleted.

Previously, I had been using an autoscaling event listener on targeted autoscaling groups, but this has the unfortunate side-effect of not catching events when autoscaling groups are initially created, as the ASG needs to be created before the subscription can be, so I'm missing instances. A workaround that I've used is to just schedule the Lambda execution every minute and have it search and apply actions, but this is severely limiting.

Is there a way for me to listen to EC2 to receive instance creation and deletion events for all EC2 instances? I have been digging around in CloudWatch and haven't found anything useful.

Comment: Did you look at EC2 state changes through CloudWatch Events? For example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#ec2_event_type

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [Amazon CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html) to trigger an AWS Lambda function when an Amazon EC2 instance changes state.

[image: Amazon CloudWatch Events Rule for EC2 events]